# copy of a list in python doesn't keep up with changes

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list that I add items to as the program runs and I have created a copy of this list so I can change/modify/examine the copy WITHOUT changing the original.

This is what I've got so far:

```
import copy
originallist.append(stuff)

combined=''.join(originallist)

copyoriginal=copy.deepcopy(originallist) 
##this didnt work as copyoriginal stayed empty [] while originallist would change.
#i also tried 
copyoriginal=list(originallist) 
#AND 
copyoriginal=originallist[:] 
#and with both cases copyoriginal remained at [] while originallist would change!!
```

Why does it not change?

Comment: I think you're on the right track, but there must be something else going on. What exactly do you mean by `"copyoriginal stayed empty []"`, if `originallist` started out with things in it? A more specific example would be helpful, with actual output and your expected output.

Comment: hi, thanks for quick reply!
what i meant by that is when i debug the program it shows me that copyoriginal is [] (by hovering the mouse over it while originallist has values in it [2,6]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to "keep up with changes" to another list, you may want to consider using a simple reference instead of a copy:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = a # b refers to a

a[0] = 3
print b # prints [3, 2, 3]
```

You can always make a copy later when you decide you want to stop tracking changes:

```
b = b[:]
```

Answer (score 1):

A copy of the list will not follow changes made to the original list; python's list are completely separate from one another once a copy has been made.

What you are trying to do is not possible without custom classes.

Comment: ohhh so is there another way to make python keep up changes with the original list and copy them to the copylist? or the only way would be to keep making copies of the original list as i add values to it each time..? thanks in advance

Comment: @3MIN3M: Exactly. Make a copy of the original list once you are done making changes, or make the changes to both lists.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to names to refer to the same object you can do this:

```
a = b = []
a.append(1)
b.append(2)
print(b)
# returns [1,2]
```

That won't let you change one of them without affecting the other, but it will let you see changes in either.